# Insufficient System resources exist to complete the requested services

Tags: java, fileutils

Getting the above error when trying to download large data using `HttpGet`

```
String uri = "";
getMethod = executeGet(uri);
httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
InputStream istream  = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(istream);
FileUtils.writeByteArraytoFile(new  File("xxx.zip"),data)
```

Comment: Please format your code when you asking question.

Comment: at which line exactly does the error occur?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a temporary byte array that might be the cause of the problem.
You can directly write the content of the stream to your file.

```
String uri = "";
getMethod = executeGet(uri);
httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
InputStream istream  = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
IOUtils.copy(istream, new FileOutputStream(new  File("xxx.zip"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the entire response into the `byte[]` (memory). Instead, you could stream the output as you read it from `istream` with something like,

```
File f = new  File("xxx.zip");
try (OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));) {
    int c = -1;
    while ((c = istream.read()) != -1) {
        os.write(c);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```